# Component not defined when Providers are loaded

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular2-services

In our Angular 2 application we have lots of services that we load like Providers in the `NgModule`, and especially a service that check the instance of a certain component.

```
if (this.appRef.components[0].instance instanceof Main) {
    return <Main>this.appRef.components[0].instance;
}
```

When SystemJS load the service, it eveluates this code and `Main` is not defined because the service is loaded before each component. Any ideas about that ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it with observable like this :

```
export class Component implements AfterViewInit {
    public instanceSubject: Subject<any>;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        instanceSubject.next(this.instance);
    }
```

Subscription in your service :

```
let mainInstance;
this.appRef.components[0].instanceSubject.asObservable().subscribe(
    (instance) => {
        if (instance instanceof Main) {
            mainInstance= <Main>instance;
        }
    }
)
```